# How to load a page from server in <iframe> / <frame> in Chrome?

Tags: html, iframe, frame, frameset

How to load a page from server in `<iframe>` / `<frame>` in Chrome? Do we have set any specific headers to load?

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <META CHARSET="UTF-8">
  <TITLE>TEST</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<FRAMESET ROWS="3%, 97%">
  <FRAME SRC="HTTPS://WWW.YAHOO.COM" BORDER="0" />
  <FRAME SRC="HTTPS://WWW.GOOGLE.COM" BORDER="0" />
</FRAMESET>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Why do you put semicolons between your attributes?

Comment: they are actually not required

Comment: <!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.01 frameset//en"
   "http://www.w3.org/tr/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="3%, 97%">
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe>
</frameset>
</html>

Comment: And again, please [edit] your question. Do not put unformatted code in comments!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: <!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.01 frameset//en"
   "http://www.w3.org/tr/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="3%, 97%">
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe>
</frameset>
</html>

Comment: I have just given yahoo and google urls. Does it load complete content?

Comment: The `frameset` tag isn't supported in HTML5.